# Build and run your Apache Stanbol instance - fails

Tags: java, apache, maven, nlp, rdf

Following the instructions on:
[stanbol build and run stanbol instance](https://stanbol.apache.org/docs/trunk/tutorial.html)

We always get the following error while executing:

```
% mvn clean install
```

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) on project org.apache.stanbol.commons.owl: There are test failures.

We assume that it has something to do with this:

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder  for further details.

The full log can be found: [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4juZt9g6iPFMDh1cDNaMWlTeUk/edit)

As we do not know what exactly went wrong we hope someone can give us some hints to find a solution.

If the tests are skipped with -DskipTests

When then lauchning the server following error appears:

```
16.07.2014 12:30:10.136 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Error starting
```

Full server log can be accessed [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4juZt9g6iPFVHNQeEtjWTZ6eFk/edit)

The result I get when using stanbol 0.12 [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4juZt9g6iPFQjdwZE1mMmFhNzA/edit) is still an error but most of the tests succeed...the version on github has a similar error [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4juZt9g6iPFWVE3aGs4cHVGb0k/edit)

And launching after skipping the tests throws this Errors showed [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4juZt9g6iPFdmRhd0pJdnJ0aGs/edit)

Comment: You Google docs link says that no preview is available.  It's probably not a great idea to encourage people to download files that they can't see ahead of time, and it'd be even better to let them read it online.  Can you post it as plain text, perhaps in a pastebin paste or something?

Comment: I changed the file to plain text thanks for the tip.

Comment: The message in the log says "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) on project org.apache.stanbol.commons.owl: There are test failures. … Please refer to /home/USER/tutorial_workspace/stanbol/commons/owl/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results."  Was there anything helpful there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not say much about the first issue with the failing tests of the `org.apache.stanbol.commons.owl` module, but I will try to provide some help with the follow up issues.

#### regarding the error of the `0.12` build:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.stanbol.commons.web.base.jersey [71]: Unable to resolve 71.0: missing requirement [71.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.1)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3962)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2025)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1279)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

In my local build the `org.apache.stanbol.commons.web.base.jersey` module depends on `org.osgi.service.http;version="[1.2.0,2)"` (according to the `MANIFEST.MF` of the bundle) and `org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.http.api:jar:2.3.0` (used since [STANBOL-1356](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STANBOL-1356)) exports version `1.2.0` of this package.

So the question to solve is why in your local build the `org.apache.stanbol.commons.web.base.jersey` module depends on version `1.2.1` instead.

#### regarding the error in the github `0.12` build

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/marmotta/ldpath/api/backend/RDFBackend : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Starting with Stanbol `0.12.1-SNAPSHOT` and `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` Java 7 is required. This is because the dependency to Apache Marmotta LDPath.

#### regarding the errors in the last linked log file

```
ERROR: Bundle org.apache.felix.http.jetty [72]: Error starting slinginstall:org.apache.felix.http.jetty-2.3.0.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.felix.http.jetty [72]: Unable to resolve 72.0: missing requirement [72.0] package; (&(package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))) org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.felix.http.jetty [72]: Unable to resolve 72.0: missing requirement [72.0] package; (&(package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundle(Felix.java:3443)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1727)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1156)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:264)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

and following ...This is caused by [STANBOL-1356](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STANBOL-1356). In fact the log contains the exact error as mentioned by the Issue. So this indicated that the pom.xml file of the launcher is missing the required updates to the `<jarWebSupport></jarWebSupport>` element. See the first comment to this issue for details.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the actual trunk version is unstable. You can check in the Stanbol Jenkins Server which is the last stable trunk version (https://builds.apache.org/view/All/job/stanbol-trunk/) Then you have to ckeck-out the last commit that ends with a stable build and try the buils process splain in Apache Stanbol web.

Comment: How can I get the last stable version of apache stanbol (the build about one month ago where all tests succeded in jenkins) ? I just see on the side older versions and the quick start where I just can execute the failing maven installation ...

Comment: To get the las stable version you have to checkout the commit that which is use generate the stable version in Jenkins. If you look in the jenkins build you can get information about the subversion commit that generate each run.

Answer (score 2):

Solution to get Apache Stanbol running:

1. Download trunk version of Stanbol on github (last commit was c8875721f7c57cb099b4c2ad8b41ea81bad3ef56 from 28.7.2014)
2. Unzip the file and place it somewhere you like it
   Ensure that in the .bashrc file JAVA_HOME is set on java version 7 before opening the terminal
3. Move in terminal to the unzipped folder of stanbol-trunk
   Run:
   *export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"*
   and then:
   *mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true*
4. to start the server run:
   *java -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -jar launchers/full/target/org.apache.stanbol.launchers.full-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -p 9090*

Heapsize for 64-bit Jvm:
*java -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M -jar launchers/full/target/org.apache.stanbol.launchers.full-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -p 9090*

Comment: Thank you, rochbenritter, for the help and actually for 64-bit Java note. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the problem

(Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project org.apache.stanbol.rules.adapters.clerezza: There are test failures.)

and was trying few things but nothing helped.
Then I cloned the git Version from https://github.com/apache/stanbol and performed again "mvn install" -> Build SUCCESS, finally

Therefore I assume there are some differences between the latest version available on https://stanbol.apache.org/downloads/ compared with the one on github.

I could be very usefull for people like me (beginners) to have the github version linked to the official website ;-)

Comment: given github repo also giving build failure

Answer (score 0):

A work around is to skip the tests, just add "-DskipTests" when invoking maven. The real solution would probably be to add a test-scoped slf4j implementation to commons/owl.

Comment: The build suceeds when skipping the tests , but stanbol throws an error when launching.